# How to resolve the error "processes exited with error(s)" in PdfLatex?

Tags: texstudio, beamerposter

I am preparing a poster (a0 size,landscape) for presentation using **TeXstudio**. This is the code for the poster

```
\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{grffile}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{drexel}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered tabularx columns
\newcommand{\pphantom}{\textcolor{ta3aluminium}} % phantom introduces a vertical space in p formatted table columns??!!

\title{\huge Drexel University Poster Template\\An Example}
\author{\href{http://www.cs.drexel.edu/~eas28/}{Evan A.~Sultanik}}
\email{\href{mailto:eas28@cs.drexel.edu}{\texttt{eas28@cs.drexel.edu}}}
\institute[Drexel University]{Department of Computer Science, Drexel University, Philadelphia, PA, USA}
\date[April 16th, 2010]{April 16th, 2010}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength{\columnheight}
\setlength{\columnheight}{105cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\noindent\begin{columns}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
    \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth}  % tweaks the width, makes a new \textwidth
      \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ % must be some better way to set the the height, width and textwidth simultaneously
        % Since all columns are the same length, it is all nice and tidy.  You have to get the height empirically
        % ---------------------------------------------------------%
        % fill each column with content            
        \begin{block}{Introduction}

                       non dolor.

        \end{block}
        \vfill
        \begin{block}{Problem Description}

                        nisl aliquam condimentum.

        \end{block}
        \vfill
        \begin{block}{Related Work}

                      et urna tempor bibendum.

        \end{block}
        \vfill
        \begin{block}{Approach}

                        neque dictum.

        \end{block}
      }
    \end{minipage}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% end the column

% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.49\textwidth}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
    \begin{minipage}[T]{.95\textwidth} % tweaks the width, makes a new \textwidth
      \parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ % must be some better way to set the the height, width and textwidth simultaneously
        % Since all columns are the same length, it is all nice and tidy.  You have to get the height empirically
        % ---------------------------------------------------------%
        % fill each column with content

        \begin{block}{The Algorithm}

                       potenti. Vestibulum vel urna vitae neque tincidunt
          pellentesque.

        \end{block}
        \vfill
        \begin{block}{Empirical Analysis}
          elem

        \end{block}
        \vfill
        \begin{block}{Future Work}

                        ultricies nunc.

        \end{block}
        \vfill
        \begin{block}{Conclusions}

                        adipiscing sapien risus a leo.

        \end{block}
      }
      % ---------------------------------------------------------%
      % end the column
    \end{minipage}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% end the column
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I got the error

> process exited with error(s)

Any help to get rid of the errors.

Comment: The errors I get are that `beamerthemedrexel.sty` is not found and that `\email` is undefined. They both disappear if I comment out the call to the theme and the line with `\email`

Comment: but I have *beamerthemedrexel.sty* in the same folder with the tex file.

Comment: It would be helpful to know *what* are the errors.

Comment: I am getting errors in the **error tab**, where to get errors

Comment: You find them listed in the `.log` file; what editor are you using?

Comment: TeXstudio version 2.3 and compling using PdfLatex

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12919/discussion-between-litun-and-egreg)

Comment: When TexStudio fails to compile it outputs such error. You can, however, see what caused the error in the log tab

Answer (score 5):

The error reporting of TeXStudio seems faulty. If I compile your document commenting the `\usetheme` line (I don't have that theme), there's still the error about `\email` that's not defined. However, as the following picture shows

[image: picture of texstudio output]

the `Undefined control sequence` error message is not reported.

With TeXworks the compiler stops:

[image]

You can find the theme and some related files at this [GitHub page](https://github.com/ying17zi/texmf/tree/master/packages-Example/beamerposter/beamerposter-drexel). However, this doesn't seem complete as [discussed in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12919/discussion-between-litun-and-egreg)

In any case, examining the log file is the only reliable way for finding and fixing errors.

Comment: I added the figure files that are required to get rid of the error. Now I am getting the error **Undefined control sequence \begin{document}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \begin{document}
Missing number, treated as zero
Undefined control sequence \begin{document}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \begin{document}
Missing number, treated as zero
Undefined control sequence \end{frame}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \end{frame}
Missing number, treated as zero
Undefined control sequence \end{frame}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) \end{frame}
Missing number, treated as 0**

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when I initially installed the softwares. The error ended in 'process exited with errors'. The solution was to open texmaker and go to options--> settings file --> reset settings. This restarts Texmaker and after that you should be fine.